# Outer bevel in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, filter

I'm new to filter editor, and it's pretty complicated. How would you approach creating outer bevel effect on shape in Inkscape?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to create bevels in Inkscape but it really depends on exactly what you're looking for and how much control you need.  Here's a great [tutorial](http://www.ryanlerch.org/blog/24/) that shows how to bevel text.  You can apply the same principles to other objects too but note that the blur option specified in step 6 is available only with text.

If you want something simple you could also try filters that come with Inkscape Filters-> Bevels.

Comment: It might be a good idea to supplement your answer by including some information from the tutorial, just in case the site goes down.